# Connect With PayPal : Get status 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-connect

I am facing 400 bad request response from PayPal during getting access token based on access code. I go through below reference link https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#1-create-the-app

I follow 5 steps perfectly but getting the issue with step no. 6. See my code below:

**Request Part:**

```
$curl = curl_init();

$base_token = "{client_id:secret}";

$data = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => '{authorization_code}'
    ),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Authorization: Basic ".$base_token,
    ),
);
curl_setopt_array($curl,$data );
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

**Response Part:**

```
stdClass Object (
    [name] => Bad Request
    [debug_id] => 5837077aa8787
    [message] => java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    [details] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

Comment: You did not actually include the curly braces in those values, right? (Those are commonly used to signal “this is a placeholder that needs replacing with an actual value”, but they are usually not _part of_ the value you need to send.)

Comment: Also, did you actually base64-encode the token?

Comment: 1. Curly braces value replace with actual value.
2. For **client_id:secret** I just used actual value, which is got from PayPal app. I think client_id and secret both are base64-encode from PayPal side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve issue see my below code:

```
$base_token = '{client_id:secret}';

$curl = curl_init();

$data = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'grant_type'=>'authorization_code',
        'code'=> $request->code,
    )),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    ),
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => $base_token
);

curl_setopt_array($curl, $data);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer - what have you changed, and why? Keep in mind that others should be able to learn from your answer

Comment: Looks like OP (1) used http_build_query, and (2) set the x-www-form-urlencoded content-type header.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will set the content type to `multipart/form-data`. This is wrong.

You need to pass a query string to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query(array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => '{authorization_code}'
    )),
```

Comment: I tried with your sugguestion but i got error, see

**stdClass Object
(
    [error] => invalid_client
    [error_description] => Client Authentication failed
)**  see my request code https://www.screencast.com/t/KFy60KwFnXCs

Comment: It doesn't look like you are base64 encoding your credentials

Comment: After used base64_encode() https://www.screencast.com/t/mSygCKssjv, I got error **stdClass Object ( [error] => invalid_authz_code [error_description] => Authorization code not found in cache )**

Comment: Which I got from PayPal callback response.

Comment: Try the same code from the command line with curl. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#sample-request

Comment: Already used same code, but If I pass **grant_type=authorization_code** then got error. If i pass **grant_type=client_credentials**  then it's work.

Comment: Client credentials aren't useful to you here. Since your request is working, this question is solved.  You will need to make sure you are set up correctly to obtain the authorization code, and if necessary ask for help showing all the steps you used for that, and include the clientid you are using in sandbox.

Comment: Authorization code not working fine for me, please review my code **https://www.screencast.com/t/O0yDm0tD5.** All setups are followed which is mention in the document.

Comment: Yes well, all steps must be reviewed, including the sandbox clientid. Contact PayPal for help if you aren't going to post a new thorough question here